# Select Records between Range from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, say `Table1` and `Table2`

**Table1**

```
╔════╦════╗
║ ID ║ RN ║
╠════╬════╣
║ 11 ║ 1  ║
║ 12 ║ 2  ║
║ 13 ║ 3  ║
║ 14 ║ 4  ║
║ 15 ║ 5  ║
║ 16 ║ 6  ║
║ 17 ║ 7  ║
║ 18 ║ 8  ║
║ 19 ║ 9  ║
║ 10 ║ 10 ║
╚════╩════╝
```

**Table2**

```
╔════╦════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ FromRN ║ ToRN ║
╠════╬════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║    1   ║  3   ║
║  2 ║    6   ║  8   ║  
║  3 ║    10  ║  10  ║
╚════╩════════╩══════╝
```

I want all those records from `Table1` whose `RN` lies between any range between `FromRN` and `ToRN` in `Table2`

So my expected output is:

```
╔════╦════╗
║ ID ║ RN ║
╠════╬════╣
║ 11 ║ 1  ║
║ 12 ║ 2  ║
║ 13 ║ 3  ║
║ 16 ║ 6  ║
║ 17 ║ 7  ║
║ 18 ║ 8  ║
║ 10 ║ 10 ║
╚════╩════╝
```

SQLFiddle to create schema can be found here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90d50

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do an `INNER JOIN` of the two tables to filter out those records from `Table1` whose `RN` values do not fall into any range in `Table2`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.RN
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.RN >= t2.FromRN AND t1.RN <= t2.ToRN
```

Follow the link below for a running demo (courtesy of the OP):

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90d50/9)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
select t1.Id, t1.RN
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.Rn between t2.FromRn and t2.ToRn
```

Answer (score 4):

And another solution is using `EXISTS` -

```
SELECT
*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2
    WHERE t1.rn >= FromRN
    AND t1.rn <= ToRN)
```

**Result**

```
| ID | RN |
|----|----|
| 11 |  1 |
| 12 |  2 |
| 13 |  3 |
| 16 |  6 |
| 17 |  7 |
| 18 |  8 |
| 20 | 10 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way too.

```
select t1.ID,t1.RN 
from Table1 as t1,Table2 as t2
where t1.RN between t2.FromRN and ToRN ;
```

Comment: This is how queries were written 30 years ago. Use joins with ON clauses.