# SQL query which checks, for each row having a date range in t1, whether there exists any recorded date in t2 within that date range?

Tags: sql

If I have two tables like so:

Table 1

```
Start      | END        | More columns ... 
------------------------------------------
2019-10-20 | 2019-10-21 |...
```

Table 2

```
Log ID | DATE  
--------------
     1 | 2019-10-20 
     2 | 2019-10-22
```

I've tried to use CASE WHEN, Boolean, Exists but I suspect my logic is wrong somewhere.

I want to return a results table which includes all of the columns from Table 1, with an additional column containing a Boolean value of whether a date within the range for that row exists in the second table.

So the result set should then look like:

```
     Start | End        | MoreCols | Available
----------------------------------------------
2019-10-20 | 2019-10-21 | …        | True
```

Comment: EXISTS should have worked.   Post your attempt to use EXISTS and the error you got so that we can help you debug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Records between Range from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148647/select-records-between-range-from-another-table)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm using SQL server. My actual goal is, instead of getting the True value, I would like for the date found to be input into this new column. This just occurred to me after I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.date between t1.start and t1.end
                         )
             then 'True' else 'False'
         end) as available_flag
from table1 t1
```

If your database supports boolean types, then you can write this as:

```
select t1.*,
       (exists (select 1 
                from table2 t2
                where t2.date between t1.start and t1.end
               )
       ) as available_flag
from table1 t1
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot with my logic. What if I wanted to replace my True with the found date?

Comment: @Karim . . . Then you would have a very different question.  For instance, what date would you want if there were multiple matches?  You should ask a *new* question to clarify.

Comment: You're right. So I should specify that within my DB it would be impossible to have two entries on the same date (as they're linked to a specific candidate ID who cannot be doubly available).